# replacing NULLs with custom values in Oracle SQL PIVOT results, when the rows are missing

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Pivot queries retun `NULL` when there's no row to be pivoted.

in the following example the COLOR attribute is missing for id=2.

```sql
with src_data (id, attr_name, attr_id, attr_type) as (
    select 1, 'ITALY', 'IT', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 1, 'GREEN', 'G', 'COLOR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 1, 'BIG', 'B', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 2, 'FRANCE', 'FR', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 2, 'SMALL', 'S', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL  --
)
select * from src_data
    PIVOT (MAX(ATTR_NAME) AS NAME, MAX(ATTR_ID) AS ID --
    FOR attr_type IN ('COUNTRY' AS "COUNTRY", 'COLOR' AS "COLOR", 'SIZE' AS "SIZE"));
```

the result is

| ID | COUNTRY_NAME | COUNTRY_ID | COLOR_NAME | COLOR_ID | SIZE_NAME | SIZE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITALY | IT | GREEN | G | BIG | B |
| 2 | FRANCE | FR | NULL | NULL | SMALL | S |

[see dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28149111a657fa1d53c617a9663d196d)

I would like to replace those null values with specific values (e.g. use `N/D` for the name and `-1` for the id).

the naive attempts do not work

- `PIVOT (NVL(MAX(ATTR_NAME), 'N/D') AS NAME ...`  gives `ORA-56902: expect aggregate function inside pivot operation`
- `PIVOT (MAX(NVL(ATTR_NAME, 'N/D')) AS NAME ...` still gives null results. My interpretation is that that NVL is never even called, since there's no row at all to be called on (where `ATTR_TYPE = 'COLOR' AND ID = 2`)

The very ugly solutions I see are

- adding the specific `NVL` logic on all the columns produced by `PIVOT`. My real life case has 14 such columns.
- adding fake rows to the `PIVOT` input to cover such cases

any better ideas?

--- edit ---

Looks like the native `pivot` cannot do this. The best I could do is adding the missing rows with an outer join and the having the `nvl` on the real `NULL`s returned by the outer join

```sql
with src_data (id, attr_name, attr_id, attr_type) as (
    select 1, 'ITALY', 'IT', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 1, 'GREEN', 'G', 'COLOR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 1, 'BIG', 'B', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 2, 'FRANCE', 'FR', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 2, 'SMALL', 'S', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL
),
     src_ids_types as (
         select src_ids.id, src_types.attr_type
         from (select distinct id from src_data) src_ids
                  cross join (select distinct attr_type from src_data) src_types
     ),
     full_data as (
         select sit.id, sit.attr_type, d.attr_name, d.attr_id
         from src_ids_types sit
                  left outer join src_data d on d.id = sit.id and d.attr_type = sit.attr_type
     )
select *
from full_data d
    PIVOT (MAX(NVL(ATTR_NAME, 'N/D')) AS NAME, MAX(NVL(ATTR_ID, -1)) AS ID --
    FOR attr_type IN ('COUNTRY' AS "COUNTRY", 'COLOR' AS "COLOR", 'SIZE' AS "SIZE"))
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=34a2036988e05da6d9ddcc46c41fdef8)

Comment: What's wrong with using `NVL()` in the outer `SELECT` clause? `SELECT *` is generally a bad practice anyway. Name the columns explicitly, and use `NVL()` as needed.

Comment: @mathguy, it's ugly because you have to repeat the NVL specific logic for all the columns returned by the pivot. If you add a new attribute type, you need to remember to add it once more in the final select.

Comment: Sorry, but your rationale doesn't make sense. You said you want to use `N/D` for the `name` column and `-1` for the `id` column, so the "placeholder" is column-dependent. If you add a new "attribute type" (whatever that means), you will have to state what "placeholder" you want for `null` for that column - where are you going to do that? Before even knowing if, when and what "attribute type" you may add? On the other hand, if all you want is to show `N/D` for `null` in **all** columns, it is **much much** easier to do that in the client program (SQL Developer, SQL\*Plus, etc.)

Comment: @mathguy I am not sure I understand your comment. Each attribute type (e.g. country) has both an ID and a NAME, and these are different columns with different semantics. When I pivot them I want the resulting NULL values to be turned into `N/D` for the NAMEs or `-1` for the IDs (there are requirements for the data warehouse design). How do we apply this logic when the attribute does not exist for the given ID? In the example for `ID=2` we don't have the `COLOR` attribute. Naively I thought that `PIVOT (NVL(MAX(ATTR_NAME), 'N/D') AS NAME` would give the correct result, but that does not work.

Comment: Your attempt can be corrected easily. What you pivot must always be an aggregate function, and `nvl` is not. The trick is to move `nvl` inside `max` (a bit inefficient, but it will work): `pivot( max(nvl(attr_name, 'N/D'/)) for ...)` But this will put `'N/D'` instead of `null` in **every** column in the output. My comment was, you don't seem to want that. You want the replacement for `null` to be different depending on the column. Sometime in the future you will add a new attribute (which is a new column after pivoting) with an entirely new `null` replacement. How can you code for that now?

Comment: Even for existing columns though - how will you be able to assign different `null` placeholders, **without** naming the columns explicitly *somewhere*, in addition to the `in` list of `pivot`? If I understand correctly, that is what you would like to avoid, and - since each attribute may use a different placeholder - I don't think you can.

Comment: @mathguy, what you suggest is what I wrote in the second bullet point in the question. Neither `nlv(max())` nor `max(nvl())` work, for different reasons.

Comment: @mathguy, I take that back. The `max(nvl())` seems to work, even in the original dbfiddle link I had posted. I'm not sure what I saw when I wrote "PIVOT (MAX(NVL(ATTR_NAME, 'N/D')) AS NAME ... still gives null results."

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by:

- Generating a list of all `attr_types` (works best if you have a table of these. You can generate a `distinct` list from the source data, but this could be slow on large data sets)
- Outer joining the data to this with a [partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) on id. This will give you a row for every attribute from the list above for every id
- Convert the `null` names/ids to N/A, -1 as appropriate in a subquery
- Passing the output to `pivot`

Which gives:

```
with src_data (id, attr_name, attr_id, attr_type) as (
  select 1, 'ITALY', 'IT', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
  select 1, 'GREEN', 'G', 'COLOR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
  select 1, 'BIG', 'B', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
  select 2, 'FRANCE', 'FR', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
  select 2, 'SMALL', 'S', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL  --
), attrs as (
  select distinct attr_type from src_data
), id_attrs as (
  select id, attr_type,
         nvl ( attr_name, 'N/A' ) attr_name,
         nvl ( attr_id, -1 ) attr_id
  from   attrs a
  left   join src_data d
    partition by ( id ) 
  using ( attr_type ) 
)
select * from id_attrs
pivot (
  max(attr_name) as name, max(attr_id) as id --
  for attr_type in (
    'COUNTRY' AS "COUNTRY", 'COLOR' AS "COLOR", 'SIZE' AS "SIZE"
  )
);

ID    COUNTRY_NAME   COUNTRY_ID   COLOR_NAME   COLOR_ID   SIZE_NAME   SIZE_ID   
    1 ITALY          IT           GREEN        G          BIG         B          
    2 FRANCE         FR           N/A          -1         SMALL       S
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the aggregate function with `CASE WHEN` to do the pivot.

```
with src_data (id, attr_name, attr_id, attr_type) as (
    select 1, 'ITALY', 'IT', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 1, 'GREEN', 'G', 'COLOR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 1, 'BIG', 'B', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 2, 'FRANCE', 'FR', 'COUNTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --
    select 2, 'SMALL', 'S', 'SIZE' FROM DUAL  --
)
SELECT ID,
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN attr_type = 'COUNTRY' THEN attr_name  END),'N/A') "COUNTRY_NAME",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN attr_type = 'COUNTRY' THEN attr_id END),'N/A') "COUNTRY_ID",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN attr_type = 'COLOR' THEN attr_name END),'N/A') "COLOR_NAME",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN attr_type = 'COLOR' THEN attr_id END),'N/A') "COLOR_ID",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN attr_type = 'SIZE' THEN attr_name END),'N/A') "SIZE_NAME",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN attr_type = 'SIZE' THEN attr_id END),'N/A') "SIZE_ID"
FROM src_data
GROUP BY ID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0769d8748aaf946119f6e2640b2f826c)

Comment: I think this case violates the rule *adding the specific NVL logic on all the columns produced by PIVOT. My real life case has 14 such columns* what OP mentions.

Comment: interesting. So you basically reimplemented the `pivot` with a heavier but more flexible syntax. Is there any possible solution with the native `pivot`?

Comment: @user103716 . . . I vote that this syntax is simpler than `pivot` -- in addition to being more flexible.  `pivot` has always seemed quite arcane to me, in addition to not being part of the SQL standard.

Comment: @user103716 - the responder here did not "reimplement" pivot. Pivoting is by definition "conditional aggregation", and what this answer shows is how pivoting was always done before Oracle introduced the `pivot` operator in version 11.1, and how pivoting is done in any other database dialect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more resilient structure rather than writing multiple `NVL()`s manually, prefer creating a stored function which will return `SYS_REFCURSOR` as data type such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Pivot_Src_Data RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols1     VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols2     VARCHAR2(32767);  
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( 'NVL('||attr_type||'_'||typ||',''N/D'') AS "'||attr_type||'_'||typ||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY attr_type ) 
    INTO v_cols1
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT attr_type, typ 
             FROM src_data
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'ID' AS typ FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'NAME' FROM dual) );

  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||attr_type||''' AS "'||attr_type||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY attr_type )
    INTO v_cols2
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT attr_type FROM src_data );
                
  v_sql := 'SELECT NVL(ID,-1) AS ID, '|| v_cols1 ||
           '  FROM src_data s
             PIVOT (MAX(attr_name) AS name, MAX(attr_id) AS id 
               FOR attr_type IN ('|| v_cols2 ||'))';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

which will be called from the *SQL Developer*'s console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :res := Pivot_Src_Data;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT res;
```

this way, no matter how many new attribute types you add to the table, you'll see all of them within the pivoted result set, unless the length of the string presented as the argument for the `LISTAGG()` function exceeds the threshold value, *which is 4000*, for the function.

Answer (score 0):

the `MAX(NVL())` syntax actually seems to provide the correct result, replacing null values even for columns that don't have corresponding rows to pivot.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=34a2036988e05da6d9ddcc46c41fdef8